# Simple loop in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, rounding, paste

I have three data...

```
[C1]
CODE VALUE
c1    0.1757
c2    0.1757
c3    0.1757

[C2]
CODE VALUE
c1    0.1757
c2    0.1757
c3    0.1757

[C3]
CODE VALUE
c1    0.1757
c2    0.1757
c3    0.1757
```

I'd like to round of the `VALUE` at digits=2 using loop function because I want to understand the loop function.

```
for(i in 1:3) {    
  a <-(paste0("c",i,"$VALUE"))
  a<-round(a,digits=2)  
}
```

Above code is fail to process what I do...

How do I adjust my code...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option would be to have the datasets in a `list`, store it in `list` and do the processing in `list`

```
lst <- lapply(mget(paste0("C", 1:3)), transform, VALUE = round(VALUE, 2))
```

---

If we really wanted to use `for` loop to modify the objects in global environment

```
nm1 <- paste0("C", 1:3)
for(nm in nm1) {
  tmp <- get(nm)
   assign(nm, `[[<-`(tmp, 'VALUE', value = round(tmp[['VALUE']], 2)))
  }
C1
#  CODE VALUE
#1   c1  0.18
#2   c2  0.18
#3   c3  0.18
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I want to use the loop function.. How do I make the code to read the variable name?..

Comment: @박주현  You can use `assign` to update the original objects, but i wouldn't recommend that

Comment: @박주현  UPdated the post with `for` loop

Comment: Thanks for your code but I don't understand this term '`[[<-`'! What is the meaning of the term in the assign function?

Comment: @박주현  It is for assigning the column to a modified value